# Return json object to client callback function

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, json, callback

I'm registering a client callback function in my C# aspx page. I want to return a javascript object from receiveServerResponse, but I'm getting a string back. How can I get the input of receiveServerResponse to be a json object? I don't want to use eval here.

```
//in aspx.cs page:
String cbReference =
            Page.ClientScript.GetCallbackEventReference(this,
            "arg", "receiveServerResponse", "context");
String callbackScript;
callbackScript = "function CallServer(arg, context)" +
            "{ " + cbReference + ";}";
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(),
            "CallServer", callbackScript, true);

//further down in aspx.cs page
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public String GetCallbackResult()

//in aspx page:
var receiveServerResponse = function (evalText) {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your problem on the JavaScript side or the C# side? It sounds like the value 'evalText' is being passed as string and if that is the case then maybe this would help:

```
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(evalText);
```

If you're returning values from JS to C# then the opposite should do the trick:

```
return JSON.stringify(jsonObject);
```